# Node.js - How to remove item from express session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Node.js - How to remove item from express session

I tried to remove an item I recently added to the session from the session. But I'm getting an error:

```
console.log('req.session:');
console.log(req.session);

req.session.checkout = 'Test';

var getSession = req.session;
console.log('getSession:');
console.log(getSession);

var { checkout, ...ret } = getSession;

console.log('ret:');
console.log(ret);

req.session = ret;

console.log('req.session:');
console.log(req.session);

console.log('req.session.checkout:');
console.log(req.session.checkout);
```

console:

```
req.session:
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-07-16T12:04:03.332Z,
     originalMaxAge: 900000,
     httpOnly: true } }
getSession:
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-07-16T12:04:03.332Z,
     originalMaxAge: 900000,
     httpOnly: true },
  checkout: 'Test' }
ret:
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-07-16T12:04:03.332Z,
     originalMaxAge: 900000,
     httpOnly: true } }
req.session:
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-07-16T12:04:03.332Z,
     originalMaxAge: 900000,
     httpOnly: true } }
req.session.checkout:
undefined
TypeError: req.session.touch is not a function
```

How do I properly remove it, so I get as result the original state back without the error?

```
req.session:
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-07-16T12:04:03.332Z,
     originalMaxAge: 900000,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Comment: Here you can remove session variable `delete req.session['<name>'];`

Comment: @xMayank Thanks! Easy as this!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe useful for those who got stuck.

You can store `sessionID = req.sessionID` when you create the session.
Then you can delete it from the session store.

```
 req.sessionStore.all((error, sessions) => {
   req.sessionStore.destroy(sessionID, (error) => {});
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
//Add 1 item to the session:
      req.session.details = {name: "a", age: 10} 

//Remove 1 item from the session:
      delete req.session.details

//Remove all from the session:
      req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err in end session');
            res.status(400).json({ message: err });
            throw Error(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('success in end session');
            res.status(200).json({ message: "success" });
        }
    })
```